# Where to find all elisp functions?

Tags: functions, help

I’m working [on this tutorial](https://benwindsorcode.github.io/Getting-Started-With-Emacs-Lisp/) and it uses functions such as,
`search-forward`, `goto-char`,  `save-excursion` etc.

Is there a place where all functions are listed?

If I search for `search-forward` I find [this tutorial page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/search_002dforward.html)  but it would be helpful to browse first to find a function.

Comment: "*a list of elisp functions*" -- if you mean "all elisp functions", please edit the title.

Comment: What are you going to do with the list? If you are hunting for useful functions, you are probably better off looking at the Elisp Reference manual for the built-in functions and then looking at the docs for each package you use. Running @shynur's code on my (farily bare-bones) setup, produces a list with almost 30000 entries. That is useful for further processing but it's too long to be usable by humans.

Comment: @NickD: "*a list with almost 30000 entries ... it's too long to be usable by humans.*" -- Exactly, so I also suggested that OP use the command `shortdoc-display-group`.  But I didn't put that into the answer, because the question is asking how to list *all* functions.

Comment: Understood (I upvoted your answer :-)) - I just wanted to make sure that the OP has a clear idea of what they want to do. It's a good policy to answer the question as it stands, but sometimes the question is only a rough approximation of what is actually required. Nevertheless, I think you *should* put it into your answer: the more complete the answer, the more useful it is in the long run IMO.

Comment: @NickD: "*I think you should put it into your answer*" -- OK, I'll take your advice. BTW, you can use `@` to mention me so that I will receive a notification.

Comment: @NickD Yes, partly my confusion. I wanted to ask how to find functions that may help for a project. For instance, I was unable to figure out how to mark and copy a word from one buffer to another. I know about `switch-to-buffer-other-window` but not how to mark and copy. The answer and other comments was useful. (although I still couldn't find the right function for this) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several methods:

- Type `C-h f <tab>` to list all functions.
- Get a list of all functions:

  ```lisp
  (let (;; Create an empty list as the value of the variable `functions'.
        (functions (list)))
     ;; Loop over all known ELisp symbols:
     (mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
                 ;; If the symbol can be treated as a function, say, a function name, e.g., `goto-char',
                 ;; push the symbol into the list `functions'.
                 (when (functionp symbol)
                   (push symbol functions))))
     ;; return `funtions'.
     functions)
  ```
- ...

---

A command that might help you or someone else with a similar question:

`shortdoc-display-group` lists common functions related to a specific topic.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a categorized list? For instance, a list of functions related to string operations?

Comment: @zeynel: Yes.  For example, `M-x shortdoc-display-group <return> string <return>` to list functions related to string.  For more information, see this command's docstring.

Comment: That's great thanks. `M-x shortdoc-display-group <TAB>` shows only 12 groups. I wonder if that covers all functions?

Comment: I tried your code in scratch. It just results in a continuous string. Hard to make sense of it. Maybe I didn't evaluate it correctly

Comment: @zeynel: "*I wonder if that covers all functions?*" -- Obviously not. ||| "*It just results in a continuous string.*" -- Again, I said that code *gets a list of all functions*. Doesn't it provide a list of all functions for you? You can write some code for yourself to print each element of that list line by line.

Comment: Yes, let me try that. It should be good practice. But if that's not too difficult, can you add a few comments on your code? I almost got it but not entirely. Thanks.

Comment: @zeynel: "*can you add a few comments on your code?*" -- No problem, my friend.

Comment: Great. Thank you.